# Assign counts from .count() to a dataframe + column names - pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hoping someone can help me here - i believe i am close to the solution.

I have a dataframe, of which i have am using .count() in order to return a series of all column names of my dataframe, and each of their respective non-NAN value counts.

Example dataframe:

| feature_1 | feature_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | NaN |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | NaN |
| 5 | 3 |

Example result for .count() here would output a series that looks like:

feature_1    5

feature_2    3

I am now trying to get this data into a dataframe, with the column names "Feature" and "Count". To have the expected output look like this:

| Feature | Count |
| --- | --- |
| feature_1 | 5 |
| feature_2 | 3 |

I am using .to_frame() to push the series to a dataframe in order to add column names. Full code:

```
df = data.count()
df = df.to_frame()
df.columns = ['Feature', 'Count']
```

However receiving this error message - "ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 2 elements", as if though it is not recognising the actual column names (Feature) as a column with values.

How can i get it to recognise both Feature and Count columns to be able to add column names to them?

Answer (score 0):

Add [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) instead [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) for 2 columns DataFrame - first column from index, second from values of Series:

```
df = data.count().reset_index()
df.columns = ['Feature', 'Count']
print (df)
     Feature  Count
0  feature_1      5
1  feature_2      3
```

Another solution with `name` parameter and [`Series.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html) or with [`DataFrame.set_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html):

```
df = data.count().rename_axis('Feature').reset_index(name='Count')
#alternative
df = data.count().reset_index().set_axis(['Feature', 'Count'], axis=1)
print (df)
     Feature  Count
0  feature_1      5
1  feature_2      3
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your new dataframe has only one column (the column name is taken as series index, then translated into dataframe index with the func `to_frame()`). In order to assign a 2 elements list to `df.columns` you have to reset the index first:

```
df = data.count()
df = df.to_frame().reset_index()
df.columns = ['Feature', 'Count']
```